# tikz array indexing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I'm trying to generate glyph plot. The idea is that I've a list of elements with 4 values (0.0 .. 1.0) that represent the value of a particular characteristic. My goal is to connect those points but I cannot access the data within the elements array. I tried some macros, and using `\pgfmathparse` with no success. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\elements{{0.5,0.5,0.59,0.5}, {0.2,0.5,0.5,0.8} }% romboide and a diamond shape

\foreach \elementPoints [count=\i] in \elements {
 \draw ({2.2*\i},0) ++(\elementPoints[1],0) node (a) {}
            ({2.2*\i},0) ++(0,\elementPoints[2]) node (b) {}
            ({2.2*\i},0) ++({-1*\elementPoints[3]},0) node (c) {}
            ({2.2*\i},0) ++(0,{-1*\elementPoints[4]}) node (d) {};

\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (a);          
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code:

You load only the packages `pgfmath` and `pgffor` but not `tikz`, yet you use `\draw` and TikZ’s path syntax. Though, they also need the `tikzpicture` environment (or the `\tikz` macro).

The index of the PGFmath arrays start at `0` not `1`.

The arrays in the `\elements` macro need another set of braces `{ }` so as do indicate that they are in fact arrays, the first pair of braces are stripped away when `\foreach` splits the list in its two arrays.

Furthermore, you use `node`s which are by default of the shape `rectangle` and have vertical and horizontal dimensions. This, I believe, is not what you want. Use `coordinate`s if you simply want to save a coordinate under a name:

```
\foreach \elementPoints [count=\i] in \elements {
  \path (2.2*\i,0) +(   \elementPoints[0],                    0) coordinate (a)
                   +(                   0,    \elementPoints[1]) coordinate (b)
                   +(-1*\elementPoints[2],                    0) coordinate (c)
                   +(                   0, -1*\elementPoints[3]) coordinate (d);

  \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
}
```

Instead of saving the coordinates and connecting them later, you can also connect them direct on the path.

---

Eitherway, maybe you are interested in a shorter version of your code using an `insert path` style and polar coordinates (which could have been used in your example, too).

#### References

- [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)

  - Difference between `+` and `++` (section 2.15 “Specifying Coordinates”, pp. 31f.)
  - Key `insert path` (chapter 14 “Syntax for Path Specications”, p. 139)
  - Take a look at the `kite` shape in section 62.3 “Geometric Shapes”, pp. 623f.

### Original approach

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\elements{{{0.5,0.5,0.59,0.5}}, {{0.2,0.5,0.5,0.8}}}% romboide and a diamond shape

\foreach \elementPoints [count=\i] in \elements
  \draw (2.2*\i,0) +(   \elementPoints[0],                    0)
                -- +(                   0,    \elementPoints[1])
                -- +(-1*\elementPoints[2],                    0)
                -- +(                   0, -1*\elementPoints[3])
                -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (original)

[image]

### Different approach

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  romb/.style args={#1:#2:#3:#4}{
    insert path={   +(right:{#1}) -- +(   up:{#2})
                 -- +( left:{#3}) -- +( down:{#4}) -- cycle
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[            draw=blue,  fill=red ] (0,0) [romb=.5:.5:.59:.5];
\draw[very thick, draw=green, fill=blue] (2,0) [romb=.2:.5:.5 :.8];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (different)

[image]